# How to use ajax to pass parameters to servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, dictionary

I'm using below code to in servlet to get the parameters from jsp page form.How to use AJAX/JQUERY to pass parameters to servlet.

```
Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myhost/my-servlet-mapping-url",
  data: {"param1":"value1"},
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log("Success!!");
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

It's regular way. What is your problem?

You've got nulls?